Next js app styles not working on pages after refreshing the page
I am building my first next.js project, migrating from create-react-app and I am having this weird issue. If I am on home page and refresh the page, styles do persist, but if I go to "/profile" page for example, or any other page besides / page, and refresh the page, the CSS styles completely disappear.
Here is my folders structure:

page.js:

    
import BlogSection from '../components/BlogSection.jsx'
import Main from '../components/Main.jsx'
import ServiceSection from '../components/ServiceSection.jsx'
import '../styles/App.css'

export default function Home() {
    return (
        <div className='home-page-container'>
            <Main />
            <ServiceSection 
                homePage
            />
            <BlogSection />
        </div>
    )
}

layout.js:

import Footer from '@/components/Footer.jsx';
import Header from '../components/Header.jsx';

export const metadata = {
  title: "Movan",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Header />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


I do not even know what to try, because I am not familiar with Next at all.

please provide the layout.js and page.js code as well

Added code and screenshots for page.js and layout.js

check out the given answer, that should fix your problem

The problem is that you've not added the globals.css file in your public layout.js file.
To fix it just add this line in the starting of your code:
import "./globals.css"

OR since in your case the CSS file is ../styles/App.css add:
import "../styles/App.css"

This would be your layout.js afterwards:
import "../styles/App.css" // ./globals.css

import Footer from '@/components/Footer.jsx';
import Header from '../components/Header.jsx';

export const metadata = {
  title: "Movan",
  description: "Generated by create next app",
};

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <Header />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}


But I do not have globals.css file. I have styles for components separately.  Could that be a problem?

Thanks a lot. Adding App.css fixed it. Thank you

happy learning!
